# remove an element of an array and resize it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to remove an element of an array and resize the size of the array.
I used:

```
selectedproducts=jQuery.grep(selectedproducts, function(value) {
    return value != thisID;
});
```

but the size of `selectedproducts` remains the same.

I use:

```
console.log(selectedproducts.length);
```

To print the `lenght` of `selectedproducts` after every delete, but it doesn't change.

Is there a function in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to do that?

**EDIT:**

I had an Array with 5 elements.

What I get in the console using [**Felix**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)'s answer after every remove:

```
Size:4 
["Celery", "Tomatoes", undefined, "Carrots"]
Size:3
["Celery", undefined, "Carrots"] 
Size:2 
[undefined, "Carrots"] 
Size:1
[undefined]
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried [**vishakvkt**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996551/vishakvkt)'s answer and works fine.

What I get in the console:

```
Size:4 
["Beans", "Avocado", "Snow Peas", "Tomatoes"] 
Size:3 
["Avocado", "Snow Peas", "Tomatoes"] 
Size:2 
["Avocado", "Snow Peas"] 
Size:1 
["Snow Peas"] 
Size:0 
[]
```

Comment: `$.grep` works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/J4cVY/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove specific element from a javascript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use `Array.splice(position_you_want_to_remove, number_of_items_to_remove)`

So if you have

```
   var a  = [1, 2, 3];
   a.splice(0, 1);  // remove one element, beginning at position 0 of the array
   console.log(a); // this will print [2,3]
```

Comment: link to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice